# How to find class field by string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a function where i look for a field based on a string input. And i want to check if the field is not null and return the row if it is not null. The exmple code shows the hardcoded else-if statement (which in reality is waaay longer). I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this. My gut says reflection but I don't know how to do this, or what to search.

```
public class Spell
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string sor { get; set; }
    public string wiz { get; set; }
    public string cleric { get; set; }
}



public IEnumerable<Spell> GetSpellsForClass(string classname)
{
    if(classname =="sor")
        return _context.Spells.Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.sor));
    else if (classname == "wiz")
        return _context.Spells.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.wiz));
    else if(classname == "cleric")
        return _context.Spells.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.cleric));
}
```

I expect an input of either 'sor', 'wiz' or 'cleric' and expect the function to search for the corresponding field, check if it is null, and return the entire object.

Comment: Have you thought of a database redesign. Replace `sor wiz cleric` etc with a field `spellType' and your search becomes common and extendable.

Comment: @Camilo, Yes good catch, small typo.
 &@Peter, I have, but this is how my data is provided. If I would do it like you suggest I would have to convert the data everytime it is supplied. Which is of course fine, but I wanted to try asking the community for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could so this:

```
_context.Spells.Where(s => typeof(Spell).GetProperty(classname).GetValue(s) != null);
```

This way you just search for the classname (I'd suggest using propertyName instead for the variable name) and don't have the if else statement.

Comment: This assumes `_context.Spells` is not an ORM. It would fail without doubt on EntityFramework and others (you cannot convert reflection code to SQL)

Comment: @Stefan That's an assumption for a terribly small table with a very small number of concurrent users.

Comment: Well this is kind of weird. You assume that this code is entity framework without pointing out why and the question doesn't mention it at all as well. So giving down votes to someone based on your unproven statement is really just inappropriate.

Comment: And you assume the question is not using it. That's why you should ask for clarification if the OP does not provide enough information, rather than answering based on assumptions. `_context.X` is the normal way of using EF and there's nothing in the question that points to the opposite. That's why I commented for the OP to clarify

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: even if that's the case, then you are basing your argument on statistics.  Although the chance is big you are correct; statistics doesn't say anything about an individual use case. Asking OP the question would help. And then, this answer still has its value since there are way more data-sources than MSSQL.

Comment: @Stefan If the case was that no ORM is being used and it's all just in memory so LINQ can actually evaluate that, this still deserves a downvote for inappropriate use of reflection code. I expect a reflection answer to either warn against the performance penalty or cache the calls.

Comment: @MirkoBrandt: please take Camilo's remarks into account.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto is right, this is on entity framework (Core). I have about 3000 spells and 22 classes in database.

Comment: I would also suggest even if this works, you should cache the result of `GetProperty` rather than calling it per spell in `Spells`.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it cleaner to use dictionary for spell types? You could have table of classes that are asociated to spell, or some different tag. Then you could have property in your class - lets say List of CharacterClasses that you could access 
ids. This would also boost in your performance, by eliminating reflections.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is a `Dictionary` to map class names to lambda methods that access the corresponding member. This will not be as efficient as your `if`/`else` (or better, a `switch`/`case`) method. NOTE: If your `switch` is long enough, the compiler might generate a hashtable of cases to lookup where to branch.

Having been reminded this is an LINQ to EF query, I have updated to build the appropriate `Expression`.

Given:

```
Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Spell, string>>> AccessSpellClass = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Spell, string>>>() {
    { "sor", s => s.sor },
    { "wiz", s => s.wiz },
    { "cleric", s => s.cleric },
};
```

And an `ExpressionVisitor` for replacing `Expression`s:

```
public static class ExpressionExt {
    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces an Expression (reference Equals) with another Expression
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orig">The original Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="from">The from Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="to">The to Expression.</param>
    /// <returns>Expression with all occurrences of from replaced with to</returns>
    public static Expression Replace(this Expression orig, Expression from, Expression to) => new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(orig);
}

/// <summary>
/// ExpressionVisitor to replace an Expression (that is Equals) with another Expression.
/// </summary>
public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    readonly Expression from;
    readonly Expression to;

    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
}
```

You can use it in your method:

```
public IEnumerable<Spell> GetSpellsForClass(string classname) {
    if (AccessSpellClass.TryGetValue(classname, out var accessExpr)) {
        Expression<Func<string,bool>> testExpr = x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x);
        var newTestBody = testExpr.Body.Replace(testExpr.Parameters[0], accessExpr.Body);
        var newTestExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Spell,bool>>(newTestBody, accessExpr.Parameters[0]);

        return _context.Spells.Where(newTestExpr);
    }
    else
        return Enumerable.Empty<Spell>();
}
```

It may be best if you create an `Attribute` and then you can have the `Dictionary` built at runtime at the beginning of your program:

```
public class UserClassAttribute : Attribute {
}

public class Spell {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    [UserClass]
    public string sor { get; set; }
    [UserClass]
    public string wiz { get; set; }
    [UserClass]
    public string cleric { get; set; }
}

void BuildAccessSpellClass() {
    var members = typeof(Spell).GetProperties();
    AccessSpellClass = new Dictionary<string, Func<Spell, string>>();
    foreach (var p in members) {
        if (p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(UserClassAttribute)) != null) {
            var className = p.Name;
            var parmS = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Spell), "s");
            var body = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parmS, p);
            var accessExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Spell,string>>(body, parmS);
            AccessSpellClass.Add(className, accessExpr);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you can't use a custom attribute, you could modify the method to take a list of property names and build dictionary entries for those properties.

Comment: Oh wow this seems like a lot of work to get it working. I was expecting a somewhat easier approach to eliminate 30 if statements. Do you recommend this approach? So far thanks for this extremely detailed approach! Will be trying it nonetheless.

Comment: @Rule For 30 if statements, I would consider switch/case instead of this, or the manual `Dictionary`. Any time you need to work with LINQ to SQL/EF, you must generate `Expression` lambdas, and that can propagate complexity. OTOH, unless your database changes during program runs, perhaps loading the spells and classes into an in-memory table (`List<Spell>`?) and using lambdas (my previous version) would be the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a reflection based answer, using an extension method, for what I think it is you actually want.

```
public static bool TryIsPropertyNull(this object obj, string PropName, out bool isNull)
{
    isNull = false;
    var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(PropName);
    if (prop == null)
        return false;
    isNull = prop.GetValue(obj) == null;
    return true;
}
```

I've done it as a "try" to account for situations where the property name is not present.
This should hopefully give you some pointers in the right direction